# Derivative of Gaussian Process using GPytorch

Tags: python, gaussian-process

I have looked this up on https://docs.gpytorch.ai/en/stable/index.html but I couldn't find information about how to get the derivative of a GP directly from GPytorch. Any idea?

Comment: Can you be a little bit more precise when you say you wan the "derivative of a GP"? Do you mean that you want the derivative of the mean function evaluated at a given point? Or maybe you want to develop the posterior distribution over the derivative?

Comment: The first one: derivative of the mean function evaluated at a given point!

Comment: on in that case, you can just use torch's built-in autodifferentiation functionality. see e.g. this tutorial: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/autogradqs_tutorial.html

Comment: if you provide some code which calculates the mean function at a point, i'll show you how to calculate its derivative